# Enable template path hint in admin pages - Magento

Tags: php, api, magento, e-commerce

I want to enable template path hints in admin panel. I know how to do it for the front end, but for back end?? I actually want to edit the admin panel .

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can do it by changing the database directly. If you have something like phpMyAdmin that is a good way to gain access. Enter this SQL.

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`)
       VALUES ('websites', '0', 'dev/debug/template_hints', '1');
```

When you are done with path hints just delete the matching record from `core_config_data` Or update the `value` field to `0` instead of deleting the whole record, it will probably be the last one since you've just added it.

Comment: If this solution doesn't work for you it could be because you have configured IPs under `developer > Developer Client Restrictions` that don't match your current IP

Comment: Don't forget that you need to flush Magento's cache in order to see the new setting effective.

Comment: I built a module for enabling hints on admin, hope this can help others  https://github.com/ledian-hymetllari/adminhints

Comment: It is better to avoid modifications directly in DB, the configuration file is a better solution.

Answer (score 35):

You can enable template and block path hints in every store (including the admin store) by setting them in the Magento configuration. To do this, simply edit your module's configuration file `config.xml` (which gets injected into Magento's global configuration).

To enable template and block path hints in the admin area add this to your `config.xml` file

```
<config>

    ...

    <stores>
        <admin>
            <dev>
                <debug>
                    <template_hints>1</template_hints>
                    <template_hints_blocks>1</template_hints_blocks>
                </debug>
            </dev>
        </admin>
    </stores>

</config>
```

To disable path hints simply change to 0, or delete the node.

Answer (score 9):

open /app/etc/local.xml  and add the follow code

```
<config>

    ...

    <websites>
        <admin>
            <dev>
                <debug>
                    <template_hints>1</template_hints>
                    <template_hints_blocks>1</template_hints_blocks>
                </debug>
            </dev>
        </admin>
    </websites>
</config>
```

Answer (score 6):

The feature wasn't designed to be used on the admin.  Its system config is explicitly set to only allow you to se this at the website or store level, not the global level.

Assuming this is just for work in a development environment, the approach I'd take would be to override the class

```
Mage_Core_Block_Template
```

and override (with a class alias override, or a local/Mage replacement) the `getShowTemplateHints` method hints.

```
public function getShowTemplateHints()
{
     //return false
     return true; 
}

//     old method, here for demo purposes only.  Don't hack the core
//     public function getShowTemplateHints()
//     {
//         if (is_null(self::$_showTemplateHints)) {
//             self::$_showTemplateHints = Mage::getStoreConfig('dev/debug/template_hints')
//                 && Mage::helper('core')->isDevAllowed();
//             self::$_showTemplateHintsBlocks = Mage::getStoreConfig('dev/debug/template_hints_blocks')
//                 && Mage::helper('core')->isDevAllowed();
//         }
//         return self::$_showTemplateHints;
//     }
```

You can then manually change getShowTemplateHints to return true or false if you want the feature on or off, or add whatever additional logic you wanted.

I would not recommend you push this change to the production server.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late but you can do it easily this way:
Just change settings in the configuration file `www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml`

Set `sections>dev>debug>fields>template_hints>show_in_default` to `1` and
set `sections>dev>debug>fields>template_hints_blocks>show_in_default` to `1` too

Comment: That doesn't affect admin pages.

Comment: Ofcorse it does. template_hints show_in_default will allow you to see the selector on Default, not on a website.
I'm actually using this and it's working.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following extension in order to enable the template path hints for frontend & backend easily & securly in a joomla way:
http://www.magepsycho.com/easy-template-path-hints.html

Answer (score 2):

A quite handy solution: Modify `getShowTemplateHints()` function defined in \app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Template.php file as below:

To run below function: In your browser type, http://www.mymagentosite.com/?th=1&token=PHP

You can see template hints and added Block Names.

```
public function getShowTemplateHints()
{
    if (is_null(self::$_showTemplateHints))
    {
        self::$_showTemplateHints = Mage::getStoreConfig('dev/debug/template_hints')
            && Mage::helper('core')->isDevAllowed();
        self::$_showTemplateHintsBlocks = Mage::getStoreConfig('dev/debug/template_hints_blocks')
            && Mage::helper('core')->isDevAllowed();
    }

    // overwrite the template hint [SPECIALLY FOR SHOWING TEMPLATE PATH HINTS IN ADMIN]
    $th     = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('th', false);
    $token  = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('token', false);
    if($th == 1 && $token == 'PHP'){
        self::$_showTemplateHints = true; // for template path
        self::$_showTemplateHintsBlocks = true; // block names
    }

    return self::$_showTemplateHints;
}
```

Comment: The `\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Template.php` file now do not have any `getShowTemplateHints()` function in magento version 1.9.3.0

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Database and Just run this query:

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (scope, scope_id, path, value)
VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/debug/template_hints', 1),
('default', 0, 'dev/debug/template_hints_blocks', 1);
```

To disable them again, run this query:

```
UPDATE core_config_data set value = 0 where scope = 'default' and scope_id = 0 and path ='dev/debug/template_hints'
```

To enable again run this query:

```
UPDATE core_config_data set value = 1 where scope = 'default' and scope_id = 0 and path ='dev/debug/template_hints'
```

Answer (score -3):

I don't think you should make it too difficult, let 's make it easy by easy steps. You can look at the instruction here about [How to turn on template path hints in Magento](http://magentoexpertforum.com/showthread.php/12659-How-to-turn-on-template-path-hints-in-magento)

Comment: The question is for back end debug not for front end. @Phuc

Comment: The question for admin and you are talking about front-end