# Locating the correct file within the Magento file structure

Tags: magento

I have been looking around Magento now for a few weeks and trying to get to grips with the file structure. While I have learnt (on a basic level) where to put code I have created and learnt to understand some of the functions but I have not learnt how to locate a required file, which I need, when I dont have a tutorial saying where that required file is.

**My question**

What questions do I need to ask myself in order to track down the necessary file(s) to edit? for example, within in the admin area (product upload tab of the "new product" page) I need to add an additional function

**What I've done**

Turned on "template path hints" (doesn't seem to work on the admin area)

Looked at generated HTML to try and make a more educated guess as to where its located

Looked at URL to try and make a more educated guess as to location

Currently I'm looking in the App/Mage/Catalog/Product/Image.php. I believe this is one of the required files I need but I will also need several other files and I have been unable to find them

Comment: Run the following query and set the value according to have template path enabled for ADMIN AREA. INSERT INTO core_config_data (scope, scope_id, path, value)
VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/debug/template_hints', 1),
('default', 0, 'dev/debug/template_hints_blocks', 1);

Cache needs to be removed. 

Check here.http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/magento/magento-template-path-hints-in-admin/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried, but it should works

> Path hints is a very useful tool for Magento Theming as it let us know
>   where exactly we have to go.
>
> It’s easy for front-end to enable the path hints and locate the
>   template file because it is available by default but it is not set up
>   for Admin area. To add option for Admin path hints in configuration
>   page we need to hack the core code.
>
> find the file in **app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml** and copy it in
>   **app/code/local/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml**. It’s a good practice to
>   always duplicate the core files in local directory.
>
> Look inside the Debug section, there will be label “Template Path
>   Hints” and “Add Block Names to Hints” set 0 (zero). Simply change it
>   to 1 (one).
>
> Next usual steps Clear System Cache
>
> Go inside **system->configuration->advanced->developers** and there will
>   be a new tab for admin path hints.

Source: http://www.techdilate.com/magento-enable-admin-template-path-hints/

And there is another solution (Database-based):
[Enable template path hint in admin pages - Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373481/enable-template-path-hint-in-admin-pages-magento)