# How to remove the footer admin page link in magento?

Tags: xml, magento, frontend, magento-1.9

How do I remove the links of the administrative page of magento ? the links of common pages I got , only the admin section that can not find

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the following file.

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/footer.phtml
```

Moreover you can enable the admin template path hints as described in the following link.

> [Enable template path hint in admin pages - Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373481/enable-template-path-hint-in-admin-pages-magento)

e.g.,

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`)
       VALUES ('websites', '0', 'dev/debug/template_hints', '1');
```

Set

> value=0

to remove hints