# Magento Additional Attribute customization

Tags: magento, attributes, backend

I have been assigned to edit a magento website and there is something that the previous developer had created in the attribute section in the Admin Dashboard.

He added the table of different pictures (as shown in the attached file) 
[image]
Now I would like to edit them but I can't find any file to edit in App/Design/ path

My assumption is that, it would be somewhere in the website engine files or something like that?

If you have any clue or answers, I will be appreciated.

Thank you,
Scott

Answer (score 0):

The file resides in the **adminhtml** folder. For code

> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/

And for design

> app/design/adminhtml/

For exact file location you can always enable the template path hint for the adminpanel.

Follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373481/enable-template-path-hint-in-admin-pages-magento) to enable the template path hint.

Hope this will help.